# How to enable logs for execution of multiple URLs through cscript.exe & *.vbs bat file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have multiple URLs to execute. I am currently using below method

I am creatving a vbs file with below content

```
Option Explicit
Dim objIEA
Set objIEA = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
objIEA.Navigate "http://www.xyz=<variable1>&abc=<variablea>"
objIEA.Navigate "http://www.xyz=<variable2>&abc=<variableb>"
objIEA.Navigate "http://www.xyz=<variable3>&abc=<variablec>"
objIEA.visible = false
While objIEA.Busy
Wend
sleep 15
objIEA.Quit
Set objIEA = Nothing
```

Here I have pasted all the URLs with all the variables & saved this file as xyz.vbs

I am executing this vbs file through batch file using below mentioned code
cscript.exe abc.VBS

The only issue is I am not able to capture the logs of the URL execution. With each URL execution, there would be a response in text which I want to capture

Pls suggest

Answer (score 0):

You may want to execute this from a cmd file, and redirect the output to a log, like below:

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR /F "tokens=1-8 delims=:/. " %%a IN ('echo %date% %time%') DO SET LogFile="C:\TEMP\applog_%%d-%%b-%%c-%%e-%%f-%%g.log"

cscript.exe abc.VBS >> %LOGFILE% 2>&1
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you can use [wget.exe](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm) to obtain the messages from execution.
For example,

```
WGET.EXE -o mylog.txt http://www.google.com
```

returns the default Google web page (index.html), and mylog.txt.
Mylog.txt contains:

```
type mylog.txt
--2011-12-21 12:24:30--  http://www.google.com/
Resolving www.google.com... 74.125.227.82, 74.125.227.83, 74.125.227.84, ...
Connecting to www.google.com|74.125.227.82|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: `index.html'

     0K .......... .                                           2.42M=0.005s

2011-12-21 12:24:30 (2.42 MB/s) - `index.html' saved [11954]
```